# What happens if i push mutliple docker :latest tags to the container registry?

Tags: docker, gitlab, continuous-deployment

Say I have this as part of a gitlab build pipeline:

> ```
> - docker build -t ${CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE}/myimage:latest -t ${CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE}/myimage:$CI_VERSION .
> - docker push --all-tags ${CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE}/myimage
> ```

Now I don't really understand what is happening here in terms of tagging. Will the latest-tag be applied to every image that is pushed into the container registry, so multiple images have this tag? Or will the container registry make sure that there's only one latest tag available which will refer to the latest container image that has been pushed.

Also, why is everyone speaking about "pushing tags" when in reality you are pushing container images? What happens if I push only one tag of a certain image and not the other, will the image be pushed with one tag only?

Comment: You can only have one image with a given tag. So when you push an image with `latest`, any image in the repository with that tag will lose it. Usually people give a new image both a version tag and the 'latest' tag, so when it loses the 'latest' tag some time in the future, you can still reference the image with the version tag.

Comment: with newer dockers, you can also do `docker build --push` (and `--pull`)

Comment: Why not try it out and see what happens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say your command creates these two tags:

```
latest
1.0.0
```

These are just names that refer to the id of the image that you've just built e.g. `0e5574283393`

**"Pushing a tag"** means you create/update this name in the registry together with the image id. This implies:

- An image, which had this tag would lose it.
- If this image id does not exist in the registry the image will be also pushed.

If later you build a new image with the same command you maybe create:

```
latest
1.0.1
```

Now you will have the following tags refering to the image id's:

| tag | image id |
| --- | --- |
| latest | 0e342283393 |
| 1.0.1 | 0e342283393 |
| 1.0.0 | 0e5574283393 |

So `latest` is just the name that should refer to the image that was built last, but in reality you could put any image behind this name

Comment: good answer but can you include what @Hans Kilian mentioned in his answer to op, that a new latest tag will make an other image "lose" its latest tag if it exists?

Answer (score 1):

```bash
docker build -t ${CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE}/myimage:latest -t ${CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE}/myimage:$CI_VERSION .
```

The order of operations:

1. The image has been built.
2. An ID (e.g. 6f6bf51237c5) has been assigned to this image.
3. ${CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE}/myimage:latest is bound to the assigned ID.
4. ${CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE}/myimage:$CI_VERSION is bound to the assigned ID.

When people talk about "pushing tags," they refer to pushing the Docker images and their associated tags to a container registry. In Docker, tags are pointers to specific images. So, when you push a tag, you essentially push the corresponding image (and tag, too, with reference to this image) to the registry.

Answer (score 1):

Container images are an assembly of multiple components, the filesystem layers, image config, and a manifest that references the layers and config. Each of these are referenced in the registry as a content addressable store, so each object can be pulled using the hash of it's content, often referred to as the digest (using the sha256 value). Pushing multiple images will push multiple manifests, each with their own sha256 digest, and you can pull them with that value if you know it.

If you don't know the digest, that's when tags are used. Tags in a registry can be thought of as a pointer or symbolic link referencing a digest of a manifest. You can have multiple tags referencing the same manifest. Or one tag can change over time, pointing to a different manifest than the last time it was queried. So when the `latest` tag is pushed multiple times, each push changes the current manifest that tag references.

Note that the `latest` tag is a convention. You may have a repository without any `latest` tag ever being pushed. Or the `latest` tag by one developer may be the most recent development push, while another developer may only update `latest` with new stable releases. It is entirely up to the developer for if and how that tag used in their repository.